# How to sum up all numbers in a list that are divisible by 2 numbers

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Hello (sorry for bad English) i have been working around trying to find out how to sum up all numbers in a list that are divisible by 2 numbers. i am not sure what too add to my code to get it right.

let's say we have a range of numbers from 0-100 and i want to find out what numbers are divisible by 3 or 10. i have calculated the sum of this and the answer should be 1953 if i haven't calculated wrong.

```
list = list(range(100))
x=0
for x in list:
    x=(x+1//10==0)
    print (x)
```

the output of this is just the row of numbers from 0-100. i have tried searching for clues, but i have only seen programs where the list is made with just around 4 numbers which where given and not a range like mine. if anyone know a sulution too this problem it would help a lot

Comment: oops. NOT list my fault. i meant instead of the variable (list) it is list1 so it is list1= list(range(100)) and for x in list1:

Comment: How is `x=(x+1//10==0)` even related to what you are trying to do? Try the builtin `sum` with a generator expression: `res = sum(x for x in ... if ... or ...)`

Comment: DON'T name your list `list`!

Comment: i thought that i need to find every number that are divisble by 10 and also 3, because i needed 2 numbers and than the sum of these. i am very new too python

Answer (score 1):

You can use: `divisors = [i for i in original_list if i%3 == 0 or i%10 == 0]`.
If you want the sum - `s = sum(divisors)`.

Answer (score 0):

use a custom function to create your list and mod 2 to find the even numbers

```
def createList(r1, r2):
    return [item for item in range(r1, r2+1)]

myList = createList(0,100)
result=[item for item in myList if item%2==0]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with the line `x=(x+1//10==0)`:

- it should probably be `(x+1)//10`, not `x + 1//10`, but if you want to get 1953, 100 seems not to be included, so rather just `x`, not `x+1`
- with `//` you do integer division, you do *not* get the remainder; for that, use modulo `%`
- you assign the result of the comparison back to `x`; instead that should probably be an `if` condition, and if that's true, add `x` to a running sum and not just print it
- you only test for one divisor, not for both

With that, your code would become this, which yields `1953` as expected:

```
res = 0
for x in range(100):
    if x % 3 == 0 or x % 10 == 0:
        res += x
```

Or shorter, using the `sum` builtin function with a generator expression:

```
res = sum(x for x in range(100) if x % 3 == 0 or x % 10 == 0)
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation. i am still very new too python and learning with if and for soo it really helps with all the explanation